# Imprimir query vazia

Tags: php

Pessoal como faço para exibir `echo` se a consulta não tiver resultados?

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST'        , "10.0.0.10");
define('DB_USER'        , "sa");
define('DB_PASSWORD'    , "@cm#db2018");
define('DB_NAME'        , "syspdv");
define('DB_DRIVER'      , "sqlsrv");


@$pesquisar = $_POST['busca'];

$codigo = str_pad($pesquisar,14, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

require_once "conexao.php";
 
try{
 
$Conexao    = Conexao::getConnection();
$query      = $Conexao->query("SELECT PRODUTO.PRODES, PRODUTO.PROPRC1 ,PRODUTO.PROPRC2,PRODUTO.PROPRC3 , CAST(ESTOQUE.ESTATU AS NUMERIC) AS ESTOQUE FROM PRODUTO inner join ESTOQUE ON PRODUTO.PROCOD = ESTOQUE.PROCOD LEFT JOIN PRODUTOAUX ON PRODUTOAUX.PROCOD=PRODUTO.PROCOD WHERE PRODUTOAUX.PROCODAUX = '$codigo' OR PRODUTO.PROCOD = '$codigo'

");
$produtos   = $query->fetchAll();
 
}catch(Exception $e){
 
echo $e->getMessage();
exit;
 
}?>
```

Comment: Eu colocaria alguns dados via query diretamente apenas para ter alguns dados para trabalhar e poder exibir seja via `echo` ou no html (para visualizar o resultado final, quando houver dados reais)

Comment: pesquisa por rowCount

Comment: esse código ai funciona só que se não tiver resultado eu não consigo colotar tipo ''produto não encontrado''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o contador de linhas do resultado da sua query e armazene em uma variável:

```
$count_row = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Então você pode usar o resultado da variável que contém a quantidade de registros de seu select.

Exemplo:

```
if($count_row==0)
{
   echo "Não tem registros para exibir";
} else
{
    // Exibe sua rotina aqui
}
```

Você pode conhecer mais sobre o [rowCount() na documentação oficial do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

> PDOStatement :: rowCount () retorna o número de linhas afetadas pela
> última instrução DELETE, INSERT ou UPDATE executada pelo objeto
> PDOStatement correspondente.

Comment: eu tentei mais também não da a mensagem